# Difference between fetch (experimental) and node-fetch

Tags: node.js, fetch-api

Is there any breaking difference between the experimental node [`fetch`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/globals.html#fetch) and the npm library [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) ?

Comment: Probably not in function, but the new one is also _browser compatible_, so any code that uses it could potentially also be ported for browsers, not relying on internal nodeJS APIs.

Answer (score 3):

**‘fetch experimental’** is also called **Global Fetch** and is based on the undici package. undici (11 in Italian) is a node module designed as an HTTP/1.1 client for NodeJS. It became heavily used in the industry, especially for services that needed to perform HTTP Streaming (e.g. huggingface/chat-ui - the open source alternative to ChatGPT) which relies on the header “Transfer-Encoding: Chunked” (note HTTP/2 no longer uses this header). This allows http streaming without the need of something like websockets. Undici matured and starting in Node18, it became known as Global Fetch in the Node documentation. Note **node-fetch** itself was originally based on **undici-fetch**. You can read about the upgrade in the v18 Release Accouncement: https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v18-release-announce:

> The implementation strives to be as close to spec-compliant as
> possible, but some aspects would require a browser environment and are
> thus omitted.

The important thing is **Global Fetch** (what the release notes from v18 called fetch - experimental) means **no polyfills** or external dependencies. This makes inroads into **true cross-platform JavaScript** because using fetch can be done on server and browser equally. Couple that with the fact that FormData, Headers, Request and Response are now in Node. Specifically, check out the Node18 documentation here for globals: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/globals.html (fetch global, class FormData, etc). All in all, use Global Fetch, as it serves as a browser-compatible implementation of the fetch() function. So if you have been using fetch in your client frameworks for time, you will be at home with the Global Fetch of Node. I felt I had to answer this since the other answer should not be considered.

**Update: January 15, 2024:**

In Node 21, Global Fetch has been marked as stable: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v21.x/docs/api/globals.html#fetch

Answer (score -2):

The main difference between the `fetch()` implementation and the `node-fetch` library is that the `node-fetch` library is a fully-featured and well-maintained library that is designed specifically for use in Node.js application.

On the other end, the experimental `fetch()` implementation is still in development and may not have all of the features or stability that `node-fetch` offers.

Comment: Can you explain what the possible missing features might be?

Comment: Why was this downvoted, this is true, the way streaming is handled for example is still being discussed. There's also no documentation for node's experimental fetch. Experimental fetch is the answer long term but until it's stable I would continue to use node-fetch in a production environment.

Comment: I'm no expert in this, but is fetch now stable (not experimental)? See https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V21.md (Oct 17 2023) and https://blog.logrocket.com/fetch-api-node-js/

Comment: @PhilipH I answered that in my answer. In Node v21, global fetch has been marked as stable.